# CefSharp doesn't accept a html with many spaces

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

CefSharp breaks an instance of embedded chrome while I pass the Html with many spaces in the script tag (Look **var __series_data__**), but if I'll compress it, all will be working.
By the way, if I pass the smaller data with spaces, it is still working.

Broken example (schematic):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">-->

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
    </style>
    <title>Stocks</title>
    <script>
        var __series_data__ = [
          {
            "name": "AA",
            "data": [
              [
                86400000,
                7.140915
              ],
              [
                345600000,
                7.05681
              ],
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "AAPL",
            "data": [
              [
                345427200000,
                0.513393
              ],
              [
                345686400000,
                0.486607
              ],
            ]
          }
       ];
       </script>
              
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <noscript>JavaScript is disabled. Please, enable JavaScript to see charts.</noscript>
                
                <div id="container" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                
                <div class="error-block"></div>
                
                <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                    
                    var seriesOptions = __series_data__;
                    
                    /**
                     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
                     * @returns {undefined}
                     */
                    function createChart() {
                    
                        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
                                
                                          rangeSelector: {
                                              selected: 1       // 3 months
                                          },
                                              
                                          navigator: {
                                              enabled: false
                                          },
                                              
                                          scrollbar: {
                                              enabled: false
                                          },
                                          
                                          credits: {
                                              enabled: false
                                          },
        
                                          yAxis: {
                                              labels: {
                                                formatter: function() {
                                                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                                                }
                                              },
                                              plotLines: [{
                                                          value: 0,
                                                          width: 2,
                                                          color: 'silver'
                                                          }]
                                          },
                                          
                                          plotOptions: {
                                              series: {
                                                compare: 'percent',
                                              }
                                          },
                                          
                                          tooltip: {
                                              pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                                              valueDecimals: 2,
                                              split: true
                                          },
                                          
                                          series: seriesOptions
                                    });
        
                        Highcharts.setOptions({
                            global: {
                                useUTC: true
                            }
                        });
        
                    }
        
                    createChart();
    </script>

    <script>
        // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
            if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
                window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
                    height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
                    slug: "None"
                }], "*");
            }
    </script>

    </body>

    <script>
        Other scripts.....
    </script>

</html>
```

Working example (schematic):

```html
<!doctype html>

    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">-->

        <style type="text/css">
            html,
                body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
        </style>
        <title>Stocks</title>
        <script>
            var__series_data__=[{"name":"AA","data":[[86400000,7.140915],[345600000,7.05681],]},{"name":"AAPL","data":[[345427200000,0.513393],[345686400000,0.486607],]}];
           </script>
                  
            </head>
            
            <body>
            <noscript>JavaScript is disabled. Please, enable JavaScript to see charts.</noscript>
                    
                    <div id="container" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                    
                    <div class="error-block"></div>
                    
                    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                        
                        var seriesOptions = __series_data__;
                        
                        /**
                         * Create the chart when all data is loaded
                         * @returns {undefined}
                         */
                        function createChart() {
                        
                            Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
                                    
                                              rangeSelector: {
                                                  selected: 1       // 3 months
                                              },
                                                  
                                              navigator: {
                                                  enabled: false
                                              },
                                                  
                                              scrollbar: {
                                                  enabled: false
                                              },
                                              
                                              credits: {
                                                  enabled: false
                                              },
            
                                              yAxis: {
                                                  labels: {
                                                    formatter: function() {
                                                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  plotLines: [{
                                                              value: 0,
                                                              width: 2,
                                                              color: 'silver'
                                                              }]
                                              },
                                              
                                              plotOptions: {
                                                  series: {
                                                    compare: 'percent',
                                                  }
                                              },
                                              
                                              tooltip: {
                                                  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                                                  valueDecimals: 2,
                                                  split: true
                                              },
                                              
                                              series: seriesOptions
                                        });
            
                            Highcharts.setOptions({
                                global: {
                                    useUTC: true
                                }
                            });
            
                        }
            
                        createChart();
        </script>

        <script>
            // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
                if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
                    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
                        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
                        slug: "None"
                    }], "*");
                }
        </script>

        </body>

        <script>
            Other scripts.....
        </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Have you filed a bug report on the cefsharp project?

Comment: CefSharp is just one of many wrappers around the Chromium embedded framework,  there's nothing here that would indicate a bug in CefSharp itself.  How does chromium behave at exactly the same version?  What error are you actually getting?  Open Devtools to find out.

Comment: DevTools sends debugging connection was closed. And a question is why is it happening?

Comment: What version of Chrome have you tested with? What version of CefSharp?  Exact version numbers.You haven't provided an error message as yet, just saying it breaks isn't particularly meaningful. Also the title is incorrect,  it's JavaScript you are having problems with,  not html.